# Can't compile class calling a method in an interface with a generic list argument

Tags: java, generics

Just got a question about generics, why doesn't this compile when using a generic List? If its not possible, anyway around it? Much appreciate any answer.

```
// Interface used in the ServiceAsync inteface.
public interface BaseObject
{
    public String getId();
}

// Class that implements the interface
public class _ModelDto implements BaseObject, IsSerializable
{
    protected String id;

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}

// Interface used in the ServiceAsync inteface.
public interface MyAsync<T>
{
     // Nothing here.
}

// Service interface use both interfaces above.
public interface ServiceAsync
{
    public void getList(MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>> callback);
}

public class MyClass
{
    ServiceAsync service = (some implementation);
    MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>> callBack = new MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>>()
    {

    };

    service.getList(callBack);  // This does not compile, says arguments are not applicable????
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got to do with the subtyping rules for parametrized types. I'll explain it in three steps:

### Non-nested case

When you have the following subtype relation (where `<:` is the symbol for "is a subtype of"):

```
_ModelDto <: BaseObject
```

The following relation does **not** hold:

```
List<_ModelDto> <: List<BaseObject>
```

But the following relations do:

```
List<_ModelDto> <: List<? extends _ModelDto> <: List<? extends BaseObject>
```

This is the reason why Java has wildcards: to enable these kind of subtype relations. All of this is explained in the [Generics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). If you understand this, we can continue with the nested case...

### Nested case

Let's do exactly the same, but with one more level of nesting. Starting from the subtype relation:

```
List<_ModelDto> <: List<? extends BaseObject>
```

The following relation does **not** hold, for exactly the same reasons as above:

```
MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>> <: MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>>
```

This is *precisely* the conversion you are trying to do when calling `service.getList(callBack)`, and since the subtype relation does not hold, the conversion fails.

However, as above, you **do** have the following relations:

```
MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>>
  <: MyAsync<? extends List<_ModelDto>>
  <: MyAsync<? extends List<? extends BaseObject>>
```

### Solution

So you should write the signature of `getList` as follows to make the call work:

```
public void getList(MyAsync<? extends List<? extends BaseObject>> callback);
```

The difference will be that the body of `getList` will be constrained with how it can use the `callback`. If `MyAsync` contains the following members:

```
public interface MyAsync<T> {
    T get();
    void set(T t);
}
```

Then, the body of `getList` will be able to `get` a list from the callback. However, it cannot `set` the list (except setting it to `null`), because it does not know exactly what kind of list is represented by the `?`.

In contrast, with your original signature, `set` is available, and that is why the compiler cannot allow your argument.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that your MyAsync interface doesn't contain any method signatures and doesn't have a particularly informative name is a code smell from my perspective, but I'll assume that this is just a dummy example. As it is written, getList() couldn't ever have any reasonable implementation that used the callback in any way; remember that type erasure will erase this method signature to `getList(MyAsync callback);`

The reason that this doesn't compile is that your bound is wrong. `MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>>` gives T as `List<? extends BaseObject>`, a list of some unknown type.

It looks to me like what you want is for the getList method itself to be generic:

```
public interface ServiceAsync {
    public <T extends BaseObject> void getList(MyAsync<List<T>> callback);
}

public class MyClass {
    public void foo() {
        ServiceAsync service = null;
        MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>> callBack = new MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>>() {};

        service.getList (callBack);  // This compiles
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is indeed that `MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>>` is not a subtype of `MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>>`, even though `_ModelDto` extends (implements) `BaseObject`. But I don't have clue why exactly that is. Any idea?

Comment: For the same reason why MyAsync<Integer> is not a subtype of MyAsync<Number>, even though Integer is a subtype of Number. I tried to clarify this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The '?' in generic types can be pretty confusing. Honestly I'm not sure why this won't compile. It has to do with using the '?' in a nested generic type. But I do know some ways to work around it.

Is there a reason that the declaration of the MyAsync in MyClass has to reference _ModelDto? It would work if you changed it to look like this:

```
   ServiceAsync service = (some implementation);
   MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>> callBack = new MyAsync<List<? extends BaseObject>>() 
   {

   };

   service.getList(callBack);
```

If you need to reference the type _ModelDto directly you could change the definition of ServiceAsync and it will fix the problem.
Change it to look like this:

```
public interface ServiceAsync<T extends BaseObject>
{
    public void getList(MyAsync<List<T>> callback);
}
```

Then add the parameter type to the declaration in MyClass

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public void method() 
   {
      ServiceAsync<_ModelDto> service = (some implementation);
      MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>> callBack = new MyAsync<List<_ModelDto>>() 
      {

      };

      service.getList(callBack);
   }
}
```